# Building only particular project in the Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (C#) I have a solution with dozens of projects. Let say I have projects: A, B, C, D, E.

Project "C" depends on "A" and "B".

"A" and "B" are not depending on any projects.

In the solution explorer I select project "C", then select "Build" (right mouse click in context menu).

But Visual Studio, along with all information in the output, displays me the list of errors in the projects "D" and "E". I.e it is trying to build other projects too.

But I did not asked for that. I want to build project "C" (also projects "A" and "B" should be built as dependendcies).

Question: How can I build **only that project I want (and its dependencies)**. And turn off this unwanted behaviour, like trying to compile projects which are in the same solution, but are not linked to the project I want to build.

**UPDATE**

Configuration manager looks like that:

[image: config-manager]

If I understand correctly all projects are marked, because they should be built when I build the whole solution. I think I can unmark all unwanted projects and leave only A, B and C.

And when I will need to build the whole solution, I will need to mark all projects again.

Is it the only solution?

I supposed when I select a project in the solution explorer and build only this project, only this project and its dependencies should be built. Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project --> Project Dependencies, select the project and then select what projects it depends on.

[image]

---

You may also want to look at the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-exclude-projects-from-a-build?view=vs-2019) on how to Exclude Projects from a Build. You can create a Custom Build and exclude the projects you don't want from it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my case project C depends only on A and B. And advised dialog shows only A and B. But Visual Studio tries to build (or do whatever) with projects D and E. And I get errors from these projects. And I don't understand why does it happening.

Comment: Interesting, I have multiple projects some which are built Individually and some that  have dependencies, it is only building what I have enabled up for that Project.  What are the dependencies for Project A and Project B ?

Comment: As I noted in my original question A and B do not depend on anything. And when I build the project C, Visual Studio should build only C and A and B as dependencies. And should not touch other projects. But I get errors from projects not related to C, and its dependencies (A and B). It makes things bad because I have about 40 projects in my legacy solution. And unwanted errors make huge mess in the output window.

Comment: What do you have setup in your Build --> Configuration Manager for your solution ?

Comment: I've updated my original question with the screenshot of configuration manager

Comment: I also updated my answer with a link on how to create a custom build configuration, that you can select instead of your main one

Comment: Thank you, I did not expect that this should be a complex task. It should be a trivial thing for users when they want to build only one project (and its dependencies) selected in the solution explorer.